# Tutorial series for RESTful api with MVC Web API

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

Does anyone have any links for building RESTful web services with the ASP.NET Web API. So far I have built a very basic web service using WCF and would now like to try the web api to see which one suits for Azure based web services.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? I can list hundreds of articles.

Comment: Im pretty new to all this. I am literately just looking for a few tutorials that explain the the ASP.NET Web API (I've never used ASP.NET MVC) and possibly shows how to put it into the cloud as a web role. I have all the tools downloaded and would like to get some basement level understanding of this new api

Comment: See my tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336862/tutorial-series-for-restful-api-with-mvc-web-api

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will start from:

- [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api): you can find screencasts, getting started info, etc (funny enough it is down at the mo)

And move on to these blogs:

- Henrik Nielsen's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/) (ASP.NET Web API architect)
- Gunnar Piepman's [blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/)
- Pedro Reys [blog](http://pedroreys.com/2012/04/04/webapicontrib/)
- Tugberk Ugurlu's [blog](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-tutorials-videos-samples)
- My own [blog](http://byterot.blogspot.com)

For asking questions, you can try here (SO) and [Web API](http://forums.asp.net/1246.aspx/1?Web%20API).

Comment: Thanks a mill. Time for a deep dive!

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336862/tutorial-series-for-restful-api-with-mvc-web-api

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I'm a sucker for a good conference presentation video (RIP MIX...)

This was my introduction to the subject and it gave me a very good crash course on the whys and hows of Web API.

[WCF Web APis: "There's a URI for That"](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM14)

A note of **caution**: The video is referencing an alpha status of the project so it may include some old terminology. But as Web API is still in beta, I think that point is kind-of moot.